# Minecraft like collision

Tags: c++, collision-detection, physics

I'm working on a Minecraft like game for educational purposes. The rendering is great so far even with `1024x1204` blocks but now that I started integrating the player collision I'm having problems.

I have a `aabb` for the player and `aabb`'s for all the blocks around him. These are created dynamically and it works out pretty fast.

My problem goes as following:

I have speed vector and the current position. For each axis I calculate the potential position and make out an aabb. I check for collisions and it's free I move there otherwise I set the speed for that component to 0. I separate the axis since I want my player to slide in a direction of partially facing a wall.

The order for the axis is y,x,z. The collision response is great but I'm having some problems with the corners as it sometimes get's stuck in the world without being able to move. Not sure what the reason is for this.

I do not want to implement actual physics since those are more demanding and basically just too much for what I need.

Do you guys have any suggestions on how to implement this in a nice way? I did some searching but I didn't find anything useful for this particular situation.

Comment: That's funny.  The real minecraft has this same bug.  First thing that comes to mind is "do not let players sit _exactly_ on the edge of a block."  Scoot them over 0.00001 of a block to one side or the other.

Comment: Super Mario Brother for NES has the same bug.  I is possable to hit a block on the wall at the 0, 0 posistion and be able to use it as a surface.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit abstract in a sense that the cause of your problem can be related to many things. From the top of my head, maybe a bug in your collision detection code: somehow it allows the objects to cross boundaries by 1 (or more) unit. So when the next collision is computed 1 or more dimension is stuck (imagine having an arm already inside the wall when collision is detected. You can't get your arm out because it collide with the interior of the wall boundary)

Comment: I highly doubt it's related to the collision checking. I used the aabb code from Ogre and that was tested long enough. The aabb's for blocks are size 1 on all axes. The player is 0.4x0.8x0.4. Basically I check for possible collisions before moving anything so I don't really see how it could inside the geometry.